# Why does an ARCore anchor lose tracking?

Tags: android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I noticed that Google hasn't provided a way to let us know why an anchor lost tracking. This is very strange because we can easily get the reason for camera tracking failure by calling `Camera.getTrackingFailureReason()` but there is no such function for an anchor.

In my experiments, I noticed that one common situation where you often lose tracking of the anchor is when you go too far from it and enter into a visually different environment which is considerably different as compared to the environment where you placed the anchor.

However, I would still like to know if any special function call can tell us precisely why an anchor loses tracking. So far, the only thing I could find in Google docs was [this](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Anchor#getTrackingState()).

Answer (score 0):

## World-tracking states

There are six cases that ARCore `TrackingFailureReason` enum has. I think these six cases are quite descriptive and exhaustive for ARCore developers, because they introduce common tracking states (in ARKit, for instance, there is almost alike set of states).

- **BAD_STATE** | *tracking lost due to bad internal state*
- **CAMERA_UNAVAILABLE** | *tracking paused due to a camera is in use by another app*
- **EXCESSIVE_MOTION** | *tracking lost due to excessive motion*
- **INSUFFICIENT_FEATURES** | *tracking lost due to low number of visual features*
- **INSUFFICIENT_LIGHT** | *tracking lost due to poor lighting conditions*
- **NONE** | *indicates that the session is initializing normally*

## About tracked anchors' states

There are incomparably more scenarios for tracked anchors, compared to the above. That's because any single anchor may be obscured, occluded, drifted, visually imperceptible, etc. Take into consideration two important things: first, in AR tracking errors are quickly accumulated over time, and a second, different Android devices have sensors that were calibrated under non-identical conditions. So, I think it is very difficult task for ARCore engineers to describe all the variants of errors that may arise due to the loss of tracking for each anchor in the scene.

Also, we have to distinguish two types of tracking: `camera tracking` (a.k.a. world tracking) and `object tracking`. This second type, i.e. `object tracking`, is about tracking anchors that additionally conform to Trackable interface (crucial for Planes, AugmentedFaces, DepthPoints, AugmentedImages).

## Why anchor loses tracking?

There's no debugging tool in ARCore for anchor that is badly tracked. In ARCore there may be many situations when your app can't track any certain anchor:

- device is too far from detected plane and its anchor (>100 meters)
- Environmental Understanding updates throughout AR experience
- lighting conditions are changed dramatically
- the anchor is drifting due to unreliable surface
- single anchor is fully or partially occluded
- you've accumulated too many tracking errors while tracked
- the anchor sits on metallic or reflected surface
- the surface texture has a repetitive pattern
- when not using ToF, surface texture is indiscernible from some distance
- when not using ToF, surface texture is barely lit
- when not using ToF, insufficient number of visual features
- when not using ToF, anchor is placed on a surface without texture
- when using ToF, maximum distance for scene reconstruction is 8 meters
- ARCore's unknown internal error
- etc...

## More about anchors

For more info, please read [this official article](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/developer-guides/anchors). In `Reuse anchors when possible` section you can find the following sentence:

> Keep in mind that, if each object in a scene has its own anchor, these anchors will adjust the object poses independently of one another in response to ARCore's estimate of world space in each frame. ***Separately anchored objects can shift or rotate relative to each other, breaking the illusion of an AR scene where virtual objects should stay in place relative to each other***.

Comment: For the anchor tracking reasons you stated, provide proof to support your argument. The TrackingFailureReason is for camera and not anchor (as I clearly mentioned in my question). Btw, many times I do not lose tracking of anchor even if I walk far away from it and enter a different environment.

Comment: As I said earlier, it's difficult to provide a proof in case we're tracking anchor (we have no debugging tools for anchors). Address your question to ARCore team members (you can do that on GitHub), I'm sure they'll give you an answer similar to mine.